# JPA with Hibernate: Query generated by Hibernate contains duplicate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The parent entity

```
class Item{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(name="ITEM_NAME")
  private String itemName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Set<Bid> bids;
....
}
```

The child entity

```
class Bid{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  private BigDecimal amount;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", nullable=false)
  private Item item;
}
```

1. I created and assigned few bids to an 'item'.
2. When I call item.getBids(), it generates

   ```
   select bids0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID3_0_0_, bids0_.id as id1_0_0_, bids0_.id as id1_0_1_, bids0_.amount as amount2_0_1_, bids0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID3_0_1_ from BID bids0_ where bids0_.ITEM_ID=?
   ```

instead a query with just bidid, ITEM_ID, amount, like

```
select bid_.id, bid_.amount as amount2_0_, bid_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID3_0_ from BID bid_ where bid_.id=?
```

If you notice the 1st query, it has two "bids0_.ITEM_ID" and two "bids0_.id" columns in the generated query. Why is this so ? Am I missing something here ? Why are those duplicate columns generated ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the multiple left joins happens with respect to Parent and child entites..Say for example, in Parent class, there is one to Many and child has many to one relationships. So when the query runs, the parent joins the child as many times the child rows available in the db.
I read in one of the forum, there are two solutions to this problem:

- Declare your joining object as a Set
- Make use of Distinct Root Entity
  Results Transformer

Hope this link may be useful…
**https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/how-to-fix-duplicate-data-from-hibernate-queries/**

Thanks!